# Nagios check_service.sh error redis-server unrecognized service

Tags: nagios

I have an issue withe Nagios Monitoring. I have following configuration:

in commands.cfg

```
define command{
        command_name    check_service.sh
        command_line    /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_service.sh -o $ARG1$ -t $ARG2$ 
}
```

in Service definition

```
define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       ARGPLUS_REDIS_SLV
        service_description             Redis Service
        check_command                   check_service.sh!linux!"service redis-server status"
        notifications_enabled           0
        }
```

I get following error:

*Current Status:      UNKNOWN   (for 0d 0h 0m 17s)
Status Information: Unknown status: redis-server: unrecognized service
Is there a typo in the command or service configuration?: redis-server: unrecognized service*

But with the same configuration just changing the process name gives me correct output

```
define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       ARGPLUS_REDIS_SLV
        service_description             Redis Service
        check_command                   check_service.sh!linux!"service nrpe status"
        notifications_enabled           0
        }
```

***Output***
*Service State Information
Current Status:   OK   (for 0d 0h 24m 20s)
Status Information: nrpe (pid 16124) is running...*

I think the minus sign in the process name redis-server is making the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the redis service can also run with name **redis**. So it could be.

```
define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       ARGPLUS_REDIS_SLV
        service_description             Redis Service
        check_command                   check_service.sh!linux!"service redis status"
        notifications_enabled           0
        }
```

To confirm run a manual check

```
 $ ./check_service.sh -o linux -t "service redis status"
```